# Copy an SQLAlcemy ORM model object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Let's say I retrieve an object from the database with this:

```py
transaction = db.query(Transaction).filter(Transaction.id == transaction_id).first()
```

And I want to make a copy of it, so I only have to update the necessary keys and keep the rest intact. Ideally I would love to convert it to a dictionary, without the hidden private keys (so no use of `__dict__`) .

`make_transient()` works, but that just makes a copy in-place and I don't want that, actually (also because the variables stay the same, and that is just confusing).

Any better tips for SQLAlchemy version >2 ?

Comment: have you tried `transaction._asdict()` ?